# how to move in a closed rectangular way around the Apple in Snake Game

Tags: algorithm, path, grid, path-finding

I am working on a snake game (Nibbles in Linux) that is played on a 60*60 field, with four snakes competing for an randomly placed apple.

I have implemented the movement of my snake with the A* (A star) algorithm.

**My Problem is this:**

When my score is more than the other snakes, I want to avoid other snakes to eat apples. So, when I am the nearest snake to apple, I want to move in a closed rectangular way to do.

You can see what I mean in this image:

[image]

(I am the green one and the red point is my head.)

There is a method in my program to do this using the A* algorithm: `setGoal(x,y);`.

My problem is that when I find a rectangle that is closed (or approximately closed), I need to follow my tail to the end of the game. So please help me make this rectangle path work.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way you can easily follow the position of your tail? If you can, you can just set the goal of your head to equal the position of your tail. If you cannot easily mark the position of your tail, then it will be more complex.

If you know how long the snake is (I'm assuming that you do, because the snake can follow a rectangular path of exactly `snakeLength` size) and it's rectangular, then you should be able to enter a state that continues looping until endOfGame == true, for example.

```
divSnakeLength = snakeLength / 4; (giving you the length of each side of the rectangle)
distanceToApple = divSnakeLength / 2;
applePosition = this.getApplePosition();
Position[] rectangleEdges = new int[2][2];

rectangleEdges[0] = {applePosition.x - distanceToApple, 
                        applePosition.y + distanceToApple};

rectangleEdges[1] = {applePosition.x + distanceToApple,
                        applePosition.y + distanceToApple};

rectangleEdges[2] = {applePosition.x + distanceToApple,
                        applePosition.y - distanceToApple};

rectangleEdges[3] = {applePosition.x - distanceToApple,
                        applePosition.y - distanceToApple};

//now we have the four corners of the rectangle

while(!endOfGame){
    foundGoal = false;
    setGoal(rectangleEdges[0]);
        while(!foundGoal(rectangleEdges[0]));
    setGoal(rectangleEdges[1]);
        while(!foundGoal(rectangleEdges[1]));
    setGoal(rectangleEdges[2]);
        while(!foundGoal(rectangleEdges[2]));
    setGoal(rectangleEdges[3]);
        while(!foundGoal(rectangleEdges[3]));
    }
```

I hope that nudges you on your way.